# How can I read migrations files at runtime and apply them to my database in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, runtime, entity-framework-migrations

How can I read migrations files at runtime and apply them to my database in EF Core?

For tests I generate my migrations files before running the tests. Now I would like to take the migrations files (I know the path to where they are generated) and apply them at runtime. How could I do that?

I know that the `dbContext.Database.Migrate();` should apply all the migrations, but the application does not happen. I think that the `Migrate()` method does not know where to look for the migrations files, so I need a way to tell him that. But I can not find an example code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think this is what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

```
options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MyApp.Migrations"));
```

and then:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

Comment: By having the 3 files, which constitute a migration, how could I tell what assembly does the migration belong to?

Comment: To create a migration I am using the `MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration` method.

Comment: Sasuke the migrations will be picked up in the order of their creation date I think. So as far as I know you can't change the order. And in my first snippet "MyApp.Migrations" stands for the assembly "MyApp.Migrations.dll"

Comment: My problem is that I can not pick up migrations at all. They are created at runtime. :(

Comment: I.e. I do not have a `.dll` file which would contain the migrations (actually one migration in my case). I just have the `Migration`, `Designer` and `Snapshot` (`.cs`) files after the `MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration`. Probably there is a way to add the three files into a `.dll` somehow? I just do not see examples of that, however hard I try to search on the internet.

Comment: Hey maybe you should use the command line to create the migration files and then apply them at run time?
To create migration you just need to run the commands listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

And then as posted previously, you can run "context.Database.Migrate" in your startup code.

Comment: that would complicate testing. Also, I am already able to generate and compile migrations to get the `.dll`. So, now the main issue remains is to apply the `.dll` at runtime.

Comment: You can do this via

context.Database.Migrate() in your startup.

So when your application starts the migration will automatically get applied.